# how SSO token is managed using wso2 Identity Server

Tags: wso2

Is there any token based Rest API, for authentication using wso2, like  openam provides REST API for authentication.

I can see there is available for OAuth token api

https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS450/OAuth+Bearer+Token-based+Authentication+for+SCIM+Endpoints

but for STS, Is there any REST API for example I am login using Username Password and I got security token I can use it session.

I had check saml SSO api example contain servlet , didn t work out for me
I have independent play web applications, my scenario is

1. web app1 login to wso2 ,
2. get sso token and saml token
3. suppose saml token expire in 10 min
4. web app1  can renew session using sso token,
5. And then request for a new saml token

Question is 
WSO2: how does my app can refresh
    login session using some token

If there is any API or using any REST API how this token is managed and re generated if SSO token is expired after some time

Thanks,